# Extending SCNNode in Swift

Tags: swift, scenekit

I would like to extend SCNNode (if possible) in Swift. Here's my attempt:

```
class MyNode : SCNNode {

    override init(geometry: SCNGeometry) -> SCNNode {
        return super.init(geometry)
    }

    /* Xcode required this */
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

The -> operator is being tagged with an error "Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ;".

I know this is not right but if I humour Xcode it "fixes" it as follows:

```
override init(geometry: SCNGeometry); -> SCNNode {
```

Which is nonsense and then Xcode complains "Expected declaration".

I don't quite understand the SCNNode implementation - if I look at it in Xcode it's all declared as abstract (in comments) and offers no implementation. The docs do not suggest anything extends from SCNNode, you instantiate it directly, so I am assuming I should be able to extend it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
class MyNode : SCNNode {
    /* Xcode required this */
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Which will inherit the designated initialiser from the base class.

If you want to specify your own initialiser that takes a geometry, you must call a designated initialiser of the base class, so I'd say this would be what you'd want:

```
class MyNode : SCNNode {
    init(geometry: SCNGeometry) {
        super.init()
        self.geometry = geometry
    }
    /* Xcode required this */
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

The initialiser you're seeing in the `SCNNode.h` code is an initialiser translated (automatically, I believe) from the Objective C method `nodeWithGeometry`. I believe this is a convenience initialiser, even though it's not specifically marked as such, which I'd personally say is a bug/limitation of the automatic header file translation. [The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html) specifically says:

> For consistency and simplicity, Objective-C factory methods get mapped as convenience initializers in Swift.

Don't be confused by the word `abstract` in the comments; this is the [HeaderDoc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/tags/tags.html) tag for a short description of a method, i.e. "abstract" is used in the sense of [an abridgement or summary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abstract#Noun).

Comment: Thanks for your thorough reply. Your first suggestion did not work - it removed the error from MyNode but added an error to the instantiation of "Cannot invoke init with an argument list of type geometry". Your 2nd suggestion did however work, so many thanks :) Noted on the header docs.

Comment: No problem. Yes; I wasn't sure whether you specifically wanted to extend SCNNode with a geometry constructor or whether you were trying it that way because the geometry constructor looked like a designated initialiser so you were trying to make the compiler happy :)