# How to give a variable or node more values

Tags: swift

For example, a `SKS` or a `SCNNode` can have things like `.position`, `.name`. How could i give it another value or property.
So i could do this:

```
if supernode.favouriteFood == "banana" {

}
```

Comment: Create a subclass of `SCNNode` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27993720/extending-scnnode-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

You can try overriding the default class.

```
class MyCustomNode: SNNode {

    var favouriteFood: String
}
```

You probably have to override some methods for all the system to work good, like `clone` and do a custom init if you want the property to be not optional

Comment: Can the class be the already made node? I mean that when i have made an SCNNode  without making it in a class, i can add the favouritefood later like this?

Comment: `SCNNode` is already a class. You have to override it to modify it. You can try an extension like @the4kman proposed, but this will modify ALL the nodes to give them the property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want every SKNode to have a given variable, you should create an `extension`:

```
extension SCNNode {
    var favouriteFood: String {
        return "banana"
    }
}
```